# Words to Differentiate Meeting Format from Meeting Structure?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I'm writing proposals for our new committee's weekly meetings. I want to write one proposal regarding everything related to how frequently we meet, where we meet, what time we meet, with whom we meet, etc. I want the other to outline the structure of the proceedings in each meeting -- like the points to cover, order of discussions to be held, what fixed tasks to carry out at the end of every meeting, whether or not we should take notes, etc.

I'm having a hard time finding unique shorthands for the above two proposals. The furthest I've gotten is to call the first one "Meeting *Format* Proposal" and the second "Meeting *Structure* Proposal", but this will still be confusing to most people. Even if I don't shorthand the entire thing -- i.e, make the title "Proposal for Meeting _______", I need something to fill in that blank.

Any suggestions? I'd much rather not having to explain each in a few words in the title. In the worst case I'll just use *Format* and *Structure* and explain it to everybody.

Comment: The second one is an "agenda" for a meeting, or if a large Robert's Rules of Order meeting is involved a "Standing Order of Proceedings". The former could be summed up as a "Meeting Schedule".  Neither format nor structure would be appropriate. A meeting format would refer to whether it was just a presentation, a question and answer, a facilitated discussion, or the like. A meeting structure would normally mean something like a PERT chart of a series of meeting designed to achieve an ultimate conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call your first document a **charter** and the second an **agenda** (with **agenda** already having been noted by John Feltz and others).

When organizations establish (charter!) committees, they typically write charters for those committees. In addition to the items you've mentioned (how frequently we meet, where we meet, what time we meet, with whom we meet, etc.), charters often contain items such as the following:

- purpose
- to whom the committee reports
- membership [who appoints members, including chair and vice-chair (or equivalent); *ex officio members*; qualifications of members (sometimes), etc.]
- term limits
- responsibilities/duties
- voting
- quorum
- rules of order
- minutes (your "whether or not we should take notes")
- administrative support

Answer (score 3):

Your second document is what I would call the *standard agenda*.  Of the elements you specify:

- Points to cover: these are agenda items
- Order of discussions: agenda items are listed in order
- Fixed tasks at the end of the meeting: also agenda items
- Whether notes should be taken: that's not part of the agenda, it
  should go in your other document.

[Agenda](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agenda)

> a list or outline of things to be considered or done